# Visual Studio Code error: "No project found in root directory. Please create a project file and add it to the configuration."

Tags: visual-studio-code, ada

I am setting up VSCode for Ada. I typed in a known good test program and tried to "Run -> Start Debugging". In the PROBLEMS (Crtl+Shift+M) window, a message appears:

"No project found in root directory. Please create a project file and add it to the configuration."

I have read the documentation and looked around in the VSCode editor and have not found anything to correct this error. Can someone provide suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The language extension is looking for a project file (`.gpr` file). Here are some instructions to set that up: https://github.com/AdaCore/ada_language_server/wiki/Getting-Started

Answer (score 0):

I saw some extra procedures inside the extension itself. There were extra steps to complete the setup. I started Ada programming with a simple text editor and the gnat compiler so these additional steps were not anticipated. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188), but please consider adding detail about the "extra steps to complete the setup."